# Can I create a view with last 7 days in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way I can create a view with last 7 days formated as DATE in mysql?

I have a query that I can use in where clause:

```
DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY )
```

but I can use it to create a standalone table.

Comment: Please provide more detail. Are you after a `VIEW` with 1 column that returns 7 rows of `date` values for the past 7 days? Or something else?

Comment: @Dai correct that is what I need

Comment: Yes. There is, and you can. Next!

Comment: @Strawberry can you prove that?